# PHP login script cannot decrypt password hash

Tags: php, authentication, password-hash

I am implementing login system from

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

I successfully connected the `config.php` to the database `mathbglogin`. When I register everything goes smoothly but when I try to login I receive an error that the password is incorrect. The database structure is as following `localhost > users > mathbglogin`. 
I tried to isolate the problem. My guess is that the password is not compared with hash in the right way(i'm new to php).

**Login if**

```
   if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                    }
                }
```

I have attached the other scripts if this can help. My second guess is that the passwords are not encrypted right for which the `register.php` can be blamed.

[Login form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twkgm.png)

[Database table preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOoSI.png)

**Full `login.php`**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
  header("location: welcome.php");
  exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM mathbglogin WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Full `register.php`**

```
   <?php
    // Include config file
    require_once "config.php";

    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
    $username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        // Validate username
        if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
            $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
        } else{
            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM mathbglogin WHERE username = ?";

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

                // Set parameters
                $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    /* store result */
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                        $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                    } else{
                        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }

        // Validate password
        if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
            $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
        } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
            $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
        } else{
            $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        }

        // Validate confirm password
        if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
            $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
        } else{
            $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
            if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
                $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
            }
        }

        // Check input errors before inserting in database
        if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

            // Prepare an insert statement
            $sql = "INSERT INTO mathbglogin (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);

                // Set parameters
                $param_username = $username;
                $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    // Redirect to login page
                    header("location: login.php");
                } else{
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
                        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

            }

            // Close statement
        }

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sign Up</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
            .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                    <label>Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
                </div>
                <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
            </form>
        </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Full `config.php`**

```
<?php
    /* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'users');

    /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ?>
```

My question is how to make the login.php logins the user.

Comment: Password hash cannot be decrypt at all! hash is one way.

Comment: to check passwords, hash the incoming password and compare with the hashed PW n the db.

Comment: jps That what I'm doing but something goes wrong. You can take a look at the screenshots

Comment: What length is your password hash field in the database?

Comment: Dharman It was 40. Now I changed it to 8096. This solved the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the password field wasn't long enough to hold the whole hash. I solved the issue by  increasing the password field length from 48 to 8096. This solved the problem. Thanks to `Dharman` for pointing out the possible issue!

Comment: A field of `varchar(255)` should do, even for future algorithms.